# "dmask" and "fmask" mount options

Tags: mount, permissions

I tried this command to mount manually :

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/external -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
```

I am not getting what `dmask` and `fmask` do here. I know they are used to set up permissions, but when I check permissions of files and folders inside the mounted directory, they are not the same as I set using `fmask` and `dmask`.

So, what are they actually doing?

Answer (score 83):

`fmask` and `dmask` are [`mount`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_mount.htm) options for the [FAT filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table), based on [`fstab`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab).

They are used to define [permissions](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php) (`umask` sets them to both files and directories, while `fmask` only applies to files and `dmask` to directories).

The masks are NOT the permissions of the file, they are used to get the permissions you want. In addition, masks can't add any permissions, they only limit what permissions a file or a directory can have.

---

The `umask` is the default for files and folders, if you want to customize files and folders’s permissions you should use `fmask` and `dmask` same use as the `umask`.

The mask permissions are not like the octal permission codes passed to the `chmod` command, however this table is really helpful understanding how the masks permissions work :

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
r   +   +   +   +   -   -   -   -
w   +   +   -   -   +   +   -   -
x   +   -   +   -   +   -   +   -
```

It works as the normal octal permissions but subtracted from 7, and use the absolute value. for instance if you want to set the permissions to `0777` you will need to set it `0000` in the `umask` (e.g. `umask=0000`), if you want to set it to `0755` you will set it to `0022` :

- The first character represents that its an octal permissions
- The second is for the owner
- The third is the group
- The fourth is for other, i.e any other user

([Source](http://www.omaroid.com/fstab-permission-masks-explained/))

---

`man mount` gives this :

```
   umask=value
          Set the umask (the bitmask  of  the  permissions  that  are  not
          present).  The default is the umask of the current process.  The
          value is given in octal.

   dmask=value
          Set the umask applied to directories only.  The default  is  the
          umask of the current process.  The value is given in octal.

   fmask=value
          Set the umask applied to regular files only.  The default is the
          umask of the current process.  The value is given in octal.
```

You'll also find examples and technical explaination from Drenriza on [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1453342&p=9115998#post9115998) and of course [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) helps a lot, as usual.

Comment: Did you try changing the first digit from 0 to others? Bitmask of 1=setuid 2=setgid 4=sticky.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the fstab mask mechanism. For example, if one wants to mount a VFAT partition like esp_part in order to access all paths and files as a non-root user, while not to write nor execute them, he may find it is awkward to do this.  If the partition is mounted with umask 0022, then the executable files become executable to all; If mounted with umask 0033, then the directories become non-accessible. The extra option fmask=0022 does not help neither, while the extra option fmask=0033 causes extra file-inaccessible problems.

Comment: Substracted from 7 for directories, substracted from 6 for files.

Comment: Same but more detailed, with examples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/umask-command-in-linux-with-examples/