# exfat drive with fstab auto mount after boot: Write permission only for set user, group has no write permission

Tags: permissions, samba, fstab, exfat

I've a exfat 14TB external drive which is auto mounted via /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=XXXX-XXX /media/my-drive exfat defaults,uid=1000,gid=1002 0 0
```

my user is (example: ubuntu) uid=1000
the group 1002 is "samba". Members of the group are root, ubuntu, plex, and a few more.

My issue is, that only ubuntu has write access to the files. The other group members don't have write permission.

How can i fix that? Is it possible to make exfat drive writeable for ALL user of the maschine? Because i want to access the drive with differen services (plex needs somtimes write access, samba to mount the drive over network in windows, and so on).

If i hit ls -l i can see, that the user and group id of the files is correctly set.

```
drwxr-xr-x   9 ubuntu samba
```

Any ideas :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group does not have write permissions. To change that add `umask=002` to the options in your fstab-line:

```
UUID=XXXX-XXX /media/my-drive exfat defaults,uid=1000,gid=1002,umask=0002 0 0
```

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/429858/590937) about the use fo the `dmask`,`fmask` and `umask` options.

You'll need to reboot to apply the change.

Comment: thank you for the fast reply! I will test it later. I will set your answer as accepted, if it works :).

Comment: Worked! Thanks :)