# can't add write permissions to mounted exFAT hard drive

Tags: permissions, mount

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 22.04 and an external USB hdd formatted as exFAT.  I can write to it as root but I can't write to it as a user.  I'd like to allow all users the ability to write to this drive.  If I try to add write permissions nothing changes.

Here's the relevant line from `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Hitachi_HDS5C3020ALA632_FFFACFF0FD000000FF4221F302FD4F-0:0-part1 /media/external auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

and here's some example console output illustrating my issue:

```
touch: cannot touch 'external/foo.txt': Permission denied
x@x-U4:/media$ ls -al
total 520
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Feb  6 21:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root   4096 Feb  5 11:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 524288 Feb  7 22:52 external
x@x-U4:/media$ chmod 777 external
chmod: changing permissions of 'external': Operation not permitted
x@x-U4:/media$ sudo !!
sudo chmod 777 external
x@x-U4:/media$ sudo chmod 777 external
x@x-U4:/media$ ls -al
total 520
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Feb  6 21:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root   4096 Feb  5 11:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 524288 Feb  7 22:52 external
x@x-U4:/media$ sudo chmod o+w external/
x@x-U4:/media$ ls -al
total 520
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Feb  6 21:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root   4096 Feb  5 11:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 524288 Feb  7 22:52 external
x@x-U4:/media$ touch external/foo.txt
touch: cannot touch 'external/foo.txt': Permission denied
x@x-U4:/media$ sudo touch external/foo.txt
x@x-U4:/media$ ls external/*.txt
external/foo.txt
```

Any idea whats going on and how I can let users write to `/media/external`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable write permissions for all users, change the `/etc/fstab` line to the following.

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Hitachi_HDS5C3020ALA632_FFFACFF0FD000000FF4221F302FD4F-0:0-part1 /media/external auto rw,user,uid=1000,dmask=0000,fmask=0000,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

ref: ["dmask" and "fmask" mount options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429848/dmask-and-fmask-mount-options)

Comment: This answer combined with the explanation of the dmask and fmask got me to my answer.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/429848/dmask-and-fmask-mount-options  to get exactly what i wanted I didn't need the uid set and dmask and fmask need to be 000, though i decided to choose a slightly more conservative mask in the end

Comment: @user1816847 Feel free to edit the answer. That will help other people in the future.